# Calling the Loop an undefined function

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want PHP to get my content through a post in Wordpress instead of just pure HTML code in the `main.php` file. So my thought was that I would just copy all my HTML code into a post on my Wordpress and use this code code in my PHP file:

```
<?php 
if(have_posts()){
while(have_posts()){
the_post();
 the_content();
   } 
 }
?>
```

When I open my website i get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function have_posts() in /var/www/fabgraphics.dk/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/BrandtsKlaedefabrik/main.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/fabgraphics.dk/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/BrandtsKlaedefabrik/main.php on line 6

HTML:
https://codepen.io/fredtube/pen/XVmjMx

GitHub repository:
https://github.com/fabruun/code-stackoverflow

Comment: why not use `get_post(post_id)`

Comment: This is a school project so we have to show that we can use the loop :)

Comment: show the whole code for better understanding where is the error

Comment: I will give you guys a link to a GitHub repository, easier that way :) just a sec

Comment: An aside - why the `if`? The `while` handles that already, yes?

Comment: @FrederikBruun posting a link is _not_ easier, and is not the recommended way to get people to look at your code.  If you want help with code, that code should be posted here.